# Issue with multi-user NAS setup

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, permissions, storage

I want to build a NAS server with multiple users. To test this I created 2 users, `pi` and `pi2`. The external drive is mounted in `/media/pi`. Here is the `ls -al` output:

`drwxrwx--x  4 pi   nasusers 4096 NAS`

The user `pi` can make files and folders with no problem. However, if `pi2` tries to do this this is the error that I get

`mkdir: cannot create directory Permission denied`

Both users are members of the `nasusers` group. Also the test directories and files made with the `pi` user belong to `pi:pi`. Shouldn't it be `pi:nasusers`? Is there any way to make it so that both users can have full access to the NAS drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/media/pi` is an inappropriate mount point, and is normally used to automount media inserted by a user, which sets permissions.

A server would normally mount a shared directory in `/mnt` or `/www` and set access permissions appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a classical unix rights problem. Let's have a look on it. To avoid confusion I set user of `/media/NAS` to `root` and then check where is the problem:

```
pi@raspberry ~$ sudo chown root /media/NAS
pi@raspberry ~$ mkdir /media/NAS/folder-pi   # works
pi@raspberry ~$ su -l pi2                    # login as pi2

pi2@raspberry ~$ mkdir /media/NAS/folder-pi2   # works
pi2@raspberry ~$ mkdir /media/NAS/folder-pi/folder-pi2
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/NAS/folder-pi/folder-pi2’: Permission denied

pi2@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -la /media/NAS/
total 16
drwxrwx--x 4 root nasusers 4096 Mar 29 10:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Mar 29 08:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi   pi       4096 Mar 29 10:12 folder-pi
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi2  pi2      4096 Mar 29 10:13 folder-pi2
pi2@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Here we can see what has happend. Both users are in group `nasusers` so each can create folders in `/media/NAS/`. But the created folders get the user and group rights from the user, so pi2 cannot access folder from pi. `/media/NAS/folder-pi` is not in group `nasusers`. Also the group rights on the new folders are only read and execute `r-x`. We have to make sure that the group is inherited from the parent folder. For this we have the `sticky bit`. Also we have to make that the group gets `rwx` rights by default. For this is the `umask`. For it`s meaning look at the internet. Lets do it:

```
pi2@raspberry ~$ rmdir /media/NAS/folder-pi2
pi2@raspberry ~$ logout
pi@raspberry ~$ rmdir /media/NAS/folder-pi

pi@raspberry ~$ sudo chmod g+s /media/NAS/   # set sticky bit
pi@raspberry ~$ ls -ld /media/NAS/           # it`s set on the group
drwxrws--x 2 root nasusers 4096 Mar 29 10:40 /media/NAS/

pi@raspberry ~$ umask 002   # set umask and check

pi@raspberry ~$ mkdir /media/NAS/folder-pi
pi@raspberry ~$ echo "hello world" >/media/NAS/folder-pi/file.pi
pi@raspberry ~$ su -l pi2

pi2@raspberry ~$ mkdir /media/NAS/folder-pi/folder-pi2
pi2@raspberry ~$ cat /media/NAS/folder-pi/file.pi
hello world
pi2@raspberry ~$ ls -la /media/NAS/folder-pi/
total 16
drwxrwsr-x 3 pi   nasusers 4096 Mar 29 10:59 .
drwxrws--x 3 root nasusers 4096 Mar 29 10:58 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi   nasusers   12 Mar 29 10:59 file.pi
drwxrwsr-x 2 pi2  nasusers 4096 Mar 29 10:59 folder-pi2
pi2@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Now it's everything as it should be. For persistent settings of the `umask` you will find some information in `~/.profile`:

> # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
>   # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
>   # umask 022

Setting the default `umask` has a little disadvantage. It`s global and works also on the filesystem of your pi, so you should have a little look at your group rights there.

And yes, as @Milliways answers you should use `/mnt/` instead of `/media/`.